# How to assign a function to a variable then call with parameters in python

Tags: python

I'm assigning a function to a variable like so:

```
def hello(name):
    print "Hello %r \n" % name

king = hello
print "%r, King of Geeks" % king("Arthur")
```

In the terminal it is returning:

Hello 'Arthur'
None, King of Geeks

What gives?

Comment: Since you do not have a `return` statement, the method returns `None`, which is what you see printed.

Comment: You may not want to be using `%r` as that returns the `repr` of the object, and likely not the string you're expecting. Try replacing that with `%s` (after implementing the suggestions below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hello()` is printing something, but returns None. (all functions return `None` by default unless you explicitly `return` something)

```
>>> result = hello('test')
Hello 'test' 

>>> print result
None
```

If you make `hello()` return the text, rather than print it, you'll get the expected result:

```
def hello(name):
    return "Hello %r \n" % name

king = hello
print "%r, King of Geeks" % king("Arthur")
```

> "Hello 'Arthur' \n", King of Geeks

I suggest using [New String Formatting](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) instead of `%` as well:

```
print "{}, King of Geeks".format(king("Arthur"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this made it all clear to me!

Answer (score 1):

Your `hello` function is `print`ing the string it creates, rather than returning it.

Then you try to substitute the return value from calling the function into another string.

Because your `hello` function doesn't return anything, it effectively returns `None` instead, hence why that gets substituted in. Just change the `print` into a `return` inside your `hello` function and things will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the *result* of the call to `king("Arthur")`, which is `None` as it does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
def hello(name):
  print("hello, %s" % name)

king = hello
king("arthur")
```

Output

```
hello, arthur
```